# Equal Spacing In print statements

Tags: java

So I was just about finished with a small little program and when I ran it everything worked fine. I did have 1 small technical issue that I didnt like and it was an unevenly spaced "table" if you would. In a nutshell I want it so my outputs are aligned on both sides.

Original output:
How many numbers should be generated?
10
What is the number of values of each random draw?
1000

```
- 1  108
- 2  90
- 3  101
- 4  98
- 5  117
- 6  97
- 7  89
- 8  111
- 9  93
- 10  96
```

Code:

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class tester
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

        Random rnum = new Random();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int num = 0;
        int length = 0;

        System.out.println("How many numbers should be generated?");
        x = in.nextInt();

       System.out.println("What is the number of values of each random draw?");
        y = in.nextInt();

        int[] roll = new int[x];
        for(int i = 1; i<=y; i++){
            num = rnum.nextInt(x);
            roll[num] = roll[num] + 1;
        }

        length = (int) Math.log10(x) + 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
            System.out.println(i+1 + "  " + roll[i]); //This is the code that prints the original output
           /*
            * This is the code I attempted that did not give the desired result
            * a = i;
            System.out.println(i+1);
            while(Math.log10(i) < length){
                System.out.print(" ");
                length--;
            }
            System.out.print(roll[i]);*/
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: yep , format specifier - width option - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the System.out.format (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) and in perticular the width option.  This is probably what you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go about this:

1) As stated already, look at the System.out.format directory. It has a wide availability of methods to format your output

2) Change the spacing in a manual way, where the spacing depends on the amount of characters in the number to the left.

Comment: On that second way, that's what I was trying to do in my original attempt but I was quite unsuccesful